# Guidance required for this handle shape in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I have to create this handle shape in ThreeJS:

[image]

I've imagined it as being a combination of a plane geometry and a twisted/squashed cone at each end with a smaller z position than the rest of the object.

I think it'd be simpler to create just one Shape for this rather than attempting to merge meshes together. Here's what I have so far:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, camera, scene, renderer;

  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    initScene();
    addGridHelper();
    addCamera();
    addRenderer();
    addOrbitControls();

    var knottedRibbonHandleTwo = createKnottedRibbonHandleTwo();
    knottedRibbonHandleTwo.position.x -= 250;
    scene.add(knottedRibbonHandleTwo);

    var sceneLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
    scene.add(sceneLight);
  }

  function createKnottedRibbonHandleTwo() {
    var belt = new THREE.Shape();
    belt.moveTo(0, 0);
    belt.lineTo(25, 0);
    belt.lineTo(25, 2.5);
    belt.lineTo(0, 2.5);

    var extrudeSettings = {
      steps: 1,
      amount: 1,
      bevelEnabled: false,
      bevelThickness: 1,
      bevelSize: 1,
      bevelSegments: 1
    };
    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(belt, extrudeSettings);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xffd700,
      wireframe: false
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.scale.multiplyScalar(20);

    return mesh;
  }

  /**** Basic Scene Setup ****/
  function initScene() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
  }

  function addCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(349.11334070460066, 405.44010726325604, 359.3111192889029);
    scene.add(camera);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2000, 2000);
    planeGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

    var planeMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial({
      opacity: 0.2
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.position.y = -200;
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(plane);

    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(2000, 100);
    // helper.position.y = -199;
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper();
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function addRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  }

  function addOrbitControls() {
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#canvas {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: -44px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
</body>
```

But I'm confused as to how I'd achieve the end parts.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need this procedurally generated?

Comment: Because it needs to scale a certain way - I had a model exported from Blender before but it would get thicker when the bag was scaled which wasn't desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Creativity is up to you. You can create [any shape](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes) you want. I just modified your snippet a bit:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, camera, scene, renderer;

  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    initScene();
    addGridHelper();
    addCamera();
    addRenderer();
    addOrbitControls();

    var knottedRibbonHandleTwo = createKnottedRibbonHandleTwo();
    knottedRibbonHandleTwo.position.x -= 250;
    scene.add(knottedRibbonHandleTwo);

    var sceneLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
    scene.add(sceneLight);
  }

  function createKnottedRibbonHandleTwo() {
    var belt = new THREE.Shape();
    belt.moveTo(0, 1.25);
    belt.lineTo(1.25, 0.5);
    belt.lineTo(2.5, 0);
    belt.lineTo(22.5, 0);
    belt.lineTo(23.75, 0.5);
    belt.lineTo(25, 1.25);
    belt.lineTo(23.75, 2);
    belt.lineTo(22.5, 2.5);
    belt.lineTo(2.5, 2.5);
    belt.lineTo(1.25, 2);

    var extrudeSettings = {
      steps: 1,
      amount: .25,
      bevelEnabled: false,
      bevelThickness: 1,
      bevelSize: 1,
      bevelSegments: 1
    };
    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(belt, extrudeSettings);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xffd700,
      wireframe: false
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.scale.setScalar(20);

    return mesh;
  }

  /**** Basic Scene Setup ****/
  function initScene() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
  }

  function addCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(349.11334070460066, 405.44010726325604, 359.3111192889029);
    scene.add(camera);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2000, 2000);
    planeGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

    var planeMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial({
      opacity: 0.2
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.position.y = -200;
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(plane);

    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(2000, 100);
    // helper.position.y = -199;
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper();
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function addRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  }

  function addOrbitControls() {
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#canvas {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: -44px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok that's a nice improvement but how about adding a curve for the z modification? I'd say it would have to the belt.bezierCurveTo() function but I'm not sure how the parameters actually interact

Comment: I've worked through this some more and I don't think the bezierCurveTo() function would work as it only works along the x and y points wherein I want to curve the shape back - i.e. on the z axis - what would recommend?

Comment: @Katana24 I'd recommend to build complex meshes, for example, in Blender. But if you want to generate it procedurally, then there's nothing on your way to change coordinates of a vertex in a geometry with any trigonometrical function (sin, cos, etc).